# apply filters to given signal

Tags: matlab, filter, filtering, signal-processing

let say we have following signal

```
function [ x ] = generate1(N,m,A3)
f1 = 100;
f2 = 200;
T = 1./f1;
t = (0:(N*T/m):(N*T))'; %'
wn = randn(length(t),1); %zero mean variance 1
x = 20.*sin(2.*pi.*f1.*t) + 30.*cos(2.*pi.*f2.*t) + A3.*wn;
%[pks,locs] = findpeaks(x);
 %plot(x)
end
```

with generation code

```
y=generate1(3,500,1);
```

now suppose that i want all components  which are with frequency below then  150,so i need  low pass filter,but how to apply in this case?please tell me,i  am new in filter design problems,can i construct filter  myself?thanks in advance

Comment: Check out the MATLAB butter() command.  You can pass in a normalized frequency and a cutoff, and specify a highpass filter and it will return the filter coefficients.  You can then apply the filter using the filtfilt() function.  Pretty straightforward.  Note: If you want frequencies below 150, you actually want a lowpass filter, but the filter design method should be the same.

Comment: yes yes you are right sorry,it is typo

Comment: please just on example how apply it ,post it as a answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
function [ x ] = generate1(N,m,A3)
f1 = 100;
f2 = 200;
T = 1./f1;
t = (0:(N*T/m):(N*T))'; %'
fs = m/(T*N);
cutoff = 150;


wn = randn(length(t),1); %zero mean variance 1
x = 20.*sin(2.*pi.*f1.*t) + 30.*cos(2.*pi.*f2.*t) + A3.*wn;

[b,a] = butter(4, cutoff/(fs/2));

x_filt = filtfilt(b,a,x);
figure; plot(t,x)
hold on
plot(t,x_filt)
%[pks,locs] = findpeaks(x);
%plot(x)
end
```

The call to the butter function constructs a 4th order butterworth lowpass filter with a cutoff frequency specified by the cutoff parameter above (In our example it is 150Hz).  the "a" and "b" values are the filter coefficients, which are applied to the x vector with the filtfilt() command.  the result "x_filt"  is a filtered version of x which contains frequency components less than 150Hz.

Comment: now what does  [b,a] = butter(4, cutoff/(fs/2));

x_filt = filtfilt(b,a,x);   do?

Comment: does it will return 4th order lowpass filter?

Comment: what is effect of low pass  filter on noise?

Comment: In this case most of the noise is at higher frequencies, so the low pass filter smooths the signal and removes most of the noise. If you set wn to zeros(length(t),1), or just input 0 as your third function input, you can see the effect the filter has on removing the noise component.

Comment: thanks very much,so low pass filter it is better  use when we know that  noises are at high frequencies right?

Comment: and one more question does it matter i use butter command or anything else?

Comment: There are many types of filters to choose from in matlab with different characteristics.  You can also play around with the filter order to get better performance.

Comment: which command  will help me to  see all the possible filters?

Comment: Probably a google search is your best bet.  You could also play around with the fdatool if you have the signal processing toolbox.  That allows you to desgin filters in a GUI environment and gives you lots of options. Just type "fdatool" in the command window.  Hope this helps!